# How to create the instance for my own type?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative, algebraic-data-types

I'm new to Haskell, learning Functor, Applicative, and Monad.

I checked the Functor instance for `Either` type from hackage is:

```
 data  Either a b  =  Left a | Right b

 instance Functor (Either a) where
    fmap _ (Left x) = Left x
    fmap f (Right y) = Right (f y)
```

and I am asked to do the Functor, Applicative, Monad instance for extended `Either` called `MyEither`:

```
data MyEither a b = MyLeft a | MyRight b | Nothing
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

My question is:

1 How to extend `Nothing` in my instance?

2 Does deriving have to be written in the instance?

Can anyone get me some tips?

Comment: To implement `fmap f` on some `MyEither a b` value `x`, find all `b`-typed values inside `x` and apply `f` to them, leaving the rest exactly as it is -- each Functor instance works in this way.

Comment: @chi what does value `x` mean?

Comment: start by calling it `MyNothing` to prevent any mixups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you implement the instance you don't need to write `deriving`. `deriving` is for when you let the compiler derive an instance for you when you are defining a new type.

For `Nothing`, pattern match on it and return `Nothing` for the implementation of all of `FAM`. There isn't much you can do with it.

Here is a similar example that may help you.

```hs
data Nope a = NopeDataJpg deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor Nope where
  fmap _ _ = NopeDataJpg
  
instance Applicative Nope where
  pure x = NopeDataJpg
  _ <*> _ = NopeDataJpg

instance Monad Nope where
  return = pure
  _ >>= _ = NopeDataJpg
```

Also, here are the [`Functor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1030), [`Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1035), and [`Monad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1048) implementations of `Maybe` in GHC. How they handle `Nothing` is pretty similar to what you need to do for your data type.

Answer (score 1):

When you write down your instances, start by writing out the types explicitly:

```
data MyEither a b = MyLeft a | MyRight b | MyNothing
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor (MyEither a) where
    -- fmap :: Functor  f => (b -> c) -> f b -> f c
    -- fmap :: (b -> c) -> MyEither a b -> MyEither a c
```

(I'll use `MyNothing` here to prevent any mix-ups with the `Maybe`'s `Nothing`).

And now we are ready to enumerate all possibilities according to the data type definition:

```
    fmap bc (MyLeft aValue) = result   where
    --   bc                ::            b -> c
    --       MyLeft aValue :: MyEither a b
    --   result            :: MyEither a      c
    .....
```

here we must produce a value of type `MyEither a c` as the result. The function `bc` is useless here, as we only have access to the value `aValue :: a` of type `a`:

```
             MyLeft aValue :: MyEither a b
           --------------------------------
                    aValue ::          a
```

Thus we have two possibilities here:

1. `result = MyLeft aValue` which will construct a new value, this time of type `MyEither a c` as determined by the type signature; or
2. `result = ...`.

Fill the dots, and make the choice between 1. and 2, completing the definition of this clause, `fmap bc (MyLeft aValue) = ...`. (but see an important note at the bottom of this post)

The next possibility is

```
    fmap bc (MyRight bValue) = ...
```

This time we do have an access to a value of type `b`, so the function `bc` can come quite handy, since

```
          bValue :: b
       bc        :: b -> c
     -------------------------
       bc bValue ::      c
```

and

```
                cValue ::            c
       --------------------------------
        myRight cValue :: MyEither a c
```

Thus the natural definition for this clause is

```
    fmap bc (MyRight bValue) = MyRight cValue
             where
             cValue =  ....
```

although of course the same second option is also technically possible as was in the first clause.<sup>(again, see an important note at the bottom of this post)</sup> What's certainly impossible is to use `MyLeft` to construct a `MyEither a c` value here, as we have absolutely no access to any `a` type value at all here.... except `undefined`.

And now there's only one more possibility left, for a value of type `MyEither a b` that our `fmap` must handle, according to its type signature (remember, `fmap :: (b -> c) -> MyEither a b -> MyEither a c`). And that value is ...

```
    fmap bc MyNothing =
```

Again, we must produce a value of type `MyEither a c` as the result. This time we have no access to any value of type neither `b` nor `a`. So there is no other choice other than return ...

```
                       .......
```

(sans the uses of `undefined` of course). Do complete the definition.

And I hope you are now able to finish up the other definitions as needed.

---

Important update: those choices mentioned above are actually no choices at all. Those possibilities do exist if all we're concerned with is making a definition that fits the type. But, the Functor etc instance must also be *lawful*. Functor laws for example are

```
  fmap id       ===  id
  fmap (f . g)  ===  fmap f . fmap g
```

and in each case only one possibility won't break the laws. In particular, `fmap id (MyLeft _) = MyNothing` breaks the first Functor law.